# Bootstrap glyphicon show up as box, but not on localhost

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xampp

So, I am using bootstrap v3.3.1, and xampp v3.1.0.
When I am opening the page locally from the server itself, the glyphicons show up fine. 
But when I connect the server to a wireless network, and try to open the page from other PC from the same network, the web loads fine, but the glyphicons show up as boxes.

Comment: Check browser console for errors. Perhaps bootstrap cannot find `fonts` directory.

Comment: 'ministryhelper.je/:1 Font from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://ministryhelper.je' is therefore not allowed access.
underscore-min.map:1 GET http://localhost/church_system/resources/js/libs/underscore-min.map 404 (Not Found)'


Here are the errors in the console.

Comment: That's the problem, you are doing `GET` request to `localhost`. Use relative urls.

Comment: I am sorry, but I really don't understand. Where do I change that? I am also using codeIgniter, by the way.

Comment: You have `localhost` as your base url. I guess you want to change it to `ministryhelper.je`.

Comment: Can you post your code?  Sounds like a fairly basic problem that a 2nd set of eyes would probably identify quickly.

Comment: Thanks for all the helps. The problems was in codeigniter config.php file.
I changed:$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/church_system'; to
$config['base_url'] = '';

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the helps. The problems was in codeigniter config.php file. 
I changed:

$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/church_system';

to

$config['base_url'] = '';

And that fixed it.